# Influence function for glm?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, diagnostic, leverage

I would like to calculate the influence of each sample on the coefficient under a logistic regression model. The R built-in function `influence()` is suppose to do exactly this. However, the result I got is different from the manual calculation.

```
sim_data <- sample(c(0,1,2), 10000, replace=T)

outcome <- sample(c(0,1), 10000, replace=T)

fit <- glm(outcome~sim_data, family=binomial)

fit2 <- glm(outcome[-1]~sim_data[-1], family=binomial)

head(influence(fit)$coefficients)

 (Intercept)      sim_data
1  0.0001161115 -0.0003466619
2 -0.0001210376  0.0003613692
3 -0.0001210376  0.0003613692
4  0.0001161115 -0.0003466619
5  0.0001161115 -0.0003466619
6  0.0001161115 -0.0003466619

fit\$coefficients[1]-fit2$coefficients[1]

(Intercept) 
9.784027e-05 

fit\$coefficients[2]-fit2$coefficients[2]

 sim_data 
-0.0002921109
```

These two numbers should equal to the first line of the `influence()` output.

Comment: The result of typing `stats:::influence.glm` suggests `R` is merely *approximating* the influence by using least-squares calculations.  BTW, you don't need to generate a huge dataset for this question: four rows will do, making it much easier to inspect the results.